# Display A popup on 'Select Options' button - Woocommere

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have Pizza ordering WP Page. I have pizza category products which are 'Simple products' and using Gravity Form Addon to let users to add extra toppings.
So, literally under each Pizza product in Shop Page there is a button called 'Select Options'. When i click that, it redirects to particular product page where user can select size and extras.
As it takes lot of steps, I want to do the above thing in the same Shop page without going in to Product page. So I want to make a popup when the user click Select Options button, the pop will have Gravity Form in it, so the user can select size of the pizza and extras in the pop and submit to cart.

I tried lot of ways:
First i tried to hide Select Options button using the hook "woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link" in Css
Here I could not hide it for only Pizza category product only.

Then i tried the below code snippet (Found in Internet) to hide the button:

```
add_action('wp', 'remove_add_to_cart_product_categories' );
 
function remove_add_to_cart_product_categories(){
    if( is_product_category( 'pizza' ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
    }
}
```

But nothing worked....

Suggestions will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

At first glance the problem here is the redirection, what you want is not possible... I think...

What do you mean by:

> I tried lot of ways: First i tried to hide Select Options button using
> the hook "woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link" in Css Here I could not
> hide it for only Pizza category product only.

Why would you want to hide it? users wouldn't have the possibility to select anymore?

**I would also suggest you to edit your question with a website link because right now there is not enough details for anyone to help...**

**EDIT 1:** On a side note **an alternative** could be to have a new products category called "Extra toping" and to display it on the pizza product page (this would be quite easier to put in place or at least possible).

Users would be able to add to cart a pizza and a topping from the same page.

this is just a simple loop through a product category, and designing a product template with an add to cart button right under a product name (I'm even pretty sure that your theme as already a template like that).

**EDIT 2:** Following my idea, if you chose to go with it:

**1_** Create a product category called "toppings".

**2_** Add your toppings as products under the toppings category

**3_** Paste the following code anywhere you want your toppings to show up (probably as a cross selling item on you product page)

```
<!-- Start loop here -->
<?php $query = new wp_query( array(
'post_type'         => 'product', // default post type for products in woocomerce is 'product'
'post_status'       => 'publish', // only published products
'posts_per_page'    => '-1', // -1 display all products
'tax_query'         => array( array(
'taxonomy'          => 'product_cat', // default custom taxonomy name for products in woocomerce is 'product_cat'
'field'             => 'slug',  // fetching category terms by slug
'terms'             => 'toppings' // your toppings category slug
), ),
) ); ?>
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ): while ( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>
<!-- Start product template here -->
<div style="
padding: 15px;
border: 1px solid;">
<h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
<a href="<?php $add_to_cart = do_shortcode('[add_to_cart_url id="'.$post->ID.'"]'); // By using the shortcode we prevent the redirect to cart page onclick... I think... Not sure
echo $add_to_cart; ?>" style="
display: block;
border-radius: .3em;
background-color: #eee;">
Add to cart - <?php echo $product = wc_get_product( $post_id ); $product->get_price(); ?></a>
</div>
<!-- End product template here -->
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
<!-- End loop here -->
```

I can't test it on my end but it should be working. If this work we can make it a modal afterwards if you want.

If you have also different kinds of product and you don't want toppings to show up for them we can also do that. (eg: don't want to show up toppings on a single drink page or single desert page)

Comment: Thanks for your reply....Thing is Each pizza has different sizes, according to each size the toppings price will be changed.Also each topping has different price too. Tha'ts why we are using Gravity forms and conditional logic to archive this.

Comment: Also, I thought i can hide the default Add to cart button for pizza products and add a custom quick view button to do the thing in a modal.....

Comment: Well the thing is you're using a new page to displays options, that where the problem is. We can do an iframe but result gonna be messy. Can you link up your website so I can take a look, it might spark something

Comment: I am developing locally at the moment.....though, i have found a plugin for quick view, that plugin replacing the AddtoCart button with another QuickView button and when we click that button that displays popup contains the actual product page but it quicker. But problem there is, the price fields are not showing up....also each product getting added twice....